# Tiddlywiki: KaTex plugin doesn't show up under ControlPanel (doesn't load)

Tags: tiddlywiki

I follow the instructions for loading the plugin, I get the green overbar, and click on "import". Still the plugin doesn't show up under '$:/ControlPanel  -> Plugins'.

How come the plugin doesn't work. I tried in Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Click to edit the content of http://tiddlywiki.com/plugins/tiddlywiki/katex/#%24%3A%2Fplugins%2Ftiddlywiki%2Fkatex, then copy-paste the entire content to a tiddler in your installation called "$:/plugins/tiddlywiki/katex". Scroll to the very bottom and set the "Type" to application/json, and create the same fields as the original (author, dependents, description, plugin-type and version).

The plugin now shows up in the control panel, and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First, asking questions on the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tiddlywiki) is a much better way to get answers. We tend to answer quickly there.

You need to save and reload your wiki after importing the plugin for the changes to take effect, otherwise it won't work. Also, are you using tiddlywiki5? The katex plugin won't work on tiddlywiki classic.

Comment: Yes I'm using tiddlywiki5.